# How to add a calculated column to pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I try to include a column that is calculated on a basis of a % difference between values of 2 columns in a pivot table.
I tried calculated field but could not figure out how to describe these columns. These are year values based on one column in dataset so I could not use just column name.

I've prepared a playground with limited data and desired result that I can make using standard formulas. But I need it to be a part of Pivot Table as this is much bigger project and includes expanding rows and changing dimensions.

Here is how it looks like (K is a column that calculates % difference between G and H columns) and I need to include this one into Pivot.

[image]

My file is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yTDExBSvRXXO3P71CH09oerFp2Is7UXqzeuwNlE5XbM/edit#gid=0

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Pivot Tables.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={{QUERY({A3:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3", 1), 
 QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({A3:C}, "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3", 1), 
 "select (Col2-Col1)/Col1 label (Col2-Col1)/Col1'Calculated column' format (Col2-Col1)/Col1 '0.00%'"))};
 {"Grand Total", INDEX(QUERY({A3:C}, "select sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null pivot Col3", 1), 2), ""}}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Beautiful query, But I don't think this can solve the problem as I need to keep it in Pivot table form. This dataset is bigger and contains more column. Some rows are collapsible. and I want to keep it this way (Pivot table is the only way you can have collapsible rows as far as I know). What I try to explore here is a Pivot table data Syntax in calculated fields and custom formulas and which is unclear for me.